# How to do text mining in MySQL to find the parentage in similar text

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5, full-text-search

I am developing a «social network system» using Laravel and MySQL,
If the user writes a post I want to see if there are similar texts in the database and display a similarity score (in percent) after comparing the post of the other post in the database.

- Can I use PHP's `similar_text` function since it will cost expensive
  time to retrieve all record from a database?
- Is there any MySQL function can do the same work of similar_text?
- The database can be large so how to make it flexible and fast with
  search?

Comment: Unfortunately NO!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT text FROM posts WHERE userid = $id AND text LIKE '%$search%'
```

Personally, I use prepared statements, but this is the general layout of what you must accomplish. That said, I personally think you should strip all posts down by sentence, then strip each sentence of any simple words like "the", "a", etc... Essentially, keywords for each sentence of a post. Then you can find sentences that match what they're currently typing in a little faster perhaps, as well as categorize your data a fair bit.

You could also use the benefits of a relational database  to allow for finding and retrieving data quickly. You never really want to use a LIKE search for something like a social network. Believe me, when you hit a million rows of data you'll be very mad if you are relying on LIKE. I promise you. I've made the mistake of bad data storage and management, but didn't realize it until it was very apparent. I had to learn the hard way basically.

I also think you should compile their language tendencies at start, and store it locally. Manipulate the text box with JS to put the burden of language logic on them. This will take the load off your DB and server in general. With a good JSON map of post keywords and sentence structure stored clientside, you can come up with some very nice lightweight predictive text. There are also HTML5 options (might need something extra I forget)  for this. You could easily use the JSON map to load in all of those options for predictions. Anyways, I think that's the way to go.